# Trigger a device action from another device on the same account

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

Is it possible to trigger a custom device action from another device that is attached to the same account?

e.g.:

- Trigger a custom device action registered to one PI from a second PI that doesn't have any custom device actions.
- Trigger a custom device action registered to one PI from an Android phone attached to the same email address.

Basically I'm trying to figure out if you have to speak directly to the device that has the custom device action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you cannot do remote execution of device actions.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Is this feature in the development roadmap? If not, why? It would be so great to have this.

Comment: I can't speak to the future roadmap.

Comment: just curious if there have any updates on this. I haven't seen much about Google Assistant SDK updates at IO this year but I thought it might be worth asking.